# Is there a way to configure INTELLIJI IDEA to be aware of hadoop framework in a docker container

Tags: docker, hadoop, intellij-idea

So I have the following setup - a linux docker container running on my windows host (using WSL2) which also has a shared volume containing my project files. I would like to make use of INTELLIJI IDEA to write some code which will use hadoop and map reduce framework inside the docker container. I want to make sure that my IDE is aware of the framework. Ideally I want to be able to run hadoop jobs (using yarn) from my IDE but I also would be happy if I can at least get the context aware autofill and shut up the linter which now complains about unexisting classes from org.apache.hadoop.

Is there a way to do that? Or if not, what would be a solution which would allow me to use a proper IDE while working with hadoop in a docker container?